# Finding $\sin 2x, \cos 2x, \tan 2x$, & finding all solutions of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am a senior in high school at the moment taking a pre-calculus course. I was out a few days this week and last due to illness and I have a big test tomorrow. Please help me figure out how to do these two problems on my review sheet, and please show me the steps!

a) $8\sin x\cos x + 4 = 0$ , find all solutions for $x$ in the interval $(0, 4\pi]$

b) $\sin x = \frac{5}{7}$ , find $\sin 2x, \cos 2x$, and $\tan 2x$
cosine is negative since it's between $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, for a), remember $sin2x=2sinxcosx$ so that equation reduces to $4sin2x+4=0$ Can you try that one?

Comment: It might be useful for you to just make flashcards of any identities from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) that you think might be on the test.  The ones that're generally most useful are the Pythagorean identity, double angle, half angle, product-to-sum, and sum-to-product formulas.  And, of course, SOH CAH TOA.

Answer (score 2):

$(a)\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

$\implies\sin2x=-1=-\sin\dfrac\pi2=\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi2\right)$

$2x=m\pi+(-1)^m\left(-\dfrac\pi2\right)$ where $m$ is any integer

For even $m,m=2n\implies2x=2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2=(4n-1)\dfrac\pi2$

For odd $m,m=2n+1\implies2x=(2n+1)\pi+\dfrac\pi2=(4n+3)\dfrac\pi2$

Observe that both cases represent actually the same set

We need $0\le(4n-1)\dfrac\pi2<4\pi\iff0\le4n-1<8\iff.25\le n<2.25\implies n=1,2$

$(b)$  See [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)  and use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$ and $\cos x<0$

Answer (score 1):

The double angle formulas for sine, cosine, and tangent are 
\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) & = 2\sin x\cos x\\
\cos(2x) & = \cos^2x - \sin^2x\\
         & = 2\cos^2x - 1\\
         & = 1 - 2\cos^2x\\
\tan(2x) & = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2x}
\end{align*}
Of course, if you know $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$, you can compute $\tan(2x)$ by dividing $\sin(2x)$ by $\cos(2x)$.

For the first problem:
\begin{align*}
8\sin x\cos x + 4 & = 0\\
2\sin x\cos x + 1 & = 0\\
\sin(2x) + 1 & = 0 && \text{using the identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$}\\
\sin(2x) & = -1\\
2x & = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = -\frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Since $x \in (0, 4\pi]$, $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$, which yields the solutions
$x = \dfrac{3\pi}{4}, \dfrac{7\pi}{4}, \dfrac{11\pi}{4}, \dfrac{15\pi}{4}$.

You can verify that these solutions are correct by direct substitution.  For instance, 
$$8\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) + 4 = 8\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) + 4 = -4 + 4 = 0$$

For the second problem:

Since $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$, $x$ is a second-quadrant angle, so $\cos x < 0$.  You know the value of $\sin x$.  To use the double angle formulas for sine and cosine, you must determine $\cos x$.  One option would be to draw a right triangle in the second quadrant with opposite side of length $5$ and hypotenuse of length $7$, then use the triangle to determine the cosine.  Otherwise, you can use the Pythagorean Identity $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ to solve for $\cos x$, remembering to take the negative root.  Once you find $\cos x$, substitute the values of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ into the double angle formulas for $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$, from which you can determine the values of the other trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use law of sines and cosines to find $\cos 2x$ and $\sin 2x$. Note that $$\tan 2x = \frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions.
A) $4\cdot\sin2x=-4$. This means $\sin2x=-1$. $\sin$ takes value $-1$ at $3\pi/2$ and $7\pi/2$ in the given domain. This means that $2x=3\pi/2$, implying $x=3\pi/4$ and similarly $2x=7\pi/2$ , therefore $x=7\pi/4$.
For b) part, just find the formulates for trigonometric double angle and since $x$ is greater than $\pi/2$ and smaller than $\pi$, $\sin$ will be positive but rest all will be negative.